# Test if the page has any broken JS/CSS includes

Tags: javascript, html, browser, browser-testing

When I move around the libraries (JS/CSS files) in a project with many HTML pages for better organization, often the pages which depend on those recently moved libraries break unless I manually update their file paths in them.

Is there any way to automatically test a page by running a headless browser and throw an error if any included JS/CSS file `404`s? I looked at CasperJS, PhantomJS and few other browser testing frameworks but couldn't find what I'm seeking to do.

I know this question can be considered broad but I'm completely lost on the subject and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Probably. Alternatively you could open up Chrome and watch the network tab and see what 404's.

Comment: I've been doing the same for sometime but I want to be able to repeat the same test on multiple pages (50+) quickly.

Comment: The readme for PhantomJS says: **Network monitoring**. Automate performance analysis, track [page loading](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Network-Monitoring) and export as standard HAR format.

Comment: I've used PhantomJS (fronted by CasperJS) for this in the past and it works quite nicely.

Comment: @Jackson Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS apparently offers [network monitoring](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Network-Monitoring).

Example ([netlog.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netlog.js)):

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

Install phantomjs and put it on your path. Save the above code as "netlog.js" and from your commandline navigate to the folder containing netlog.js and run the command `phantomjs netlog.js "http://www.example.com"`.